# Meta analysis average percentage difference with standard error

Tags: mean, meta-analysis, error, percentage

I am collecting data on the effect calorie labeling has.  Each study provides a value for mean calories consumed before the calorie label and after.  Each number has a standard error or deviation associated with it.  I want to combine multiple studies and calculate a mean percentage change with a standard error value.  How would I go about this?  Thanks for reading

Comment: You can use the post intervention means and SD. You can also calculate the change score (and SD). The formula is in the Cochrane Handbook. You won't be able to calculate the % change from baseline with the reported results; you would need the individual patient data for that. I would say just use the post intervention means and SDs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I'll try that